# How to get insurance after trip extended due to flight cancellation, when existing insurance refuses to extend?

Tags: uk-citizens, insurance, cancellations, new-zealand, emirates

My wife (a UK passport holder) is in New Zealand and had her Emirates flight to Heathrow cancelled. Now her insurance company (Brokersure) will not extend her cover as she cannot get a flight until next week.

What can she do?

Comment: What is her citizenship? Which insurance company? Cover for what? What are their T&C? Which airline?

Comment: If your wife's existing insurer has declined to extend cover her only option is to seek cover elsewhere. I'd say it's extremely unlikely that she'll get cover from another insurer but you'd have to phone them and ask: it's not something you'll find on a Web site. Failing that, she'll have no insurance. She won't be the first to travel uninsured.

Comment: Out of interest, which flight was cancelled? I'm literally on a Dubai to Auckland Emirates flight right now, which indicates there should be a return flight as normal.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.worldnomads.com/travel-insurance

They let you get the insurance when you’re already abroad.
I don’t have personal experience with them as I am using a Dutch one (which I also started using when already abroad), but world nomads is fairly well known.